# Can I remove KDE applications from Kubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, kde, uninstall

I just made the switch to Kubuntu 11.10 and I'm loving it!  But I have the annoyances of the software being on here.

For starters, it comes with Rekonq and KMail by default, so I installed Firefox and Thunderbird.  Can I uninstall Rekonq and KMail and not mess up my KDE desktop?  I saw something how it is all integrated into the system and I didn't want to mess up my new installation already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to uninstall them - just check that they don't try to pull too many dependencies with them.

However, their sizes on disk are 3Mb and 4Mb respectively - are you that short on disk space? I would just leave them.

Answer (score 2):

**Simulation - what will hapen if...**

```
~$ sudo apt-get -s purge rekonq

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rekonq*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Purg rekonq [0.8.0-0ubuntu0.1]



:~$ sudo apt-get -s purge kmail

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kmail*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Purg kmail [4:4.7.2+git111007-0ubuntu1]
```

**Man Pages**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com

```
man apt-get


   purge
       purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged 
       (any configuration files are deleted too).

   -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
       No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not 
       actually change the system.
```

**Defaults**

The Kubuntu desktop is wrapped up by the Kubuntu developers. The default applications are picked (mainly) from the KDE and the Qt applications.

The KDE-base (the nucleus of KDE, namely the minimal package set necessary to run KDE as a desktop environment.) /1/, /2/ is having the: dolphin, kde-baseapps-bin, kdepasswd, kfind, konqueror, plasma-widget-folderview as dependency.

Here is an older example of building a barebone KDE installation: http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3106858.0

Links:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages
2. http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/kde-baseapps

Answer (score 1):

When I double-click on a .html file, KDE opens it in rekonq. I tried to use the file association settings to change this behavior, but even if firefox is higher in the list than rekonq, KDE keeps opening rekonq. That's why I'm going to try to remove rekonq. It would be great if it would obey the same rules as the other applications.

Comment: If possible could you add a solution to the question, if you can't these sort of posts are more use in the comments below a question rather than an "answer". I'll upvote so you can get started with comments quicker.

Comment: For future readers: uninstalling rekonq does not fix this behaviour, it just causes an error message to popup whenever you try to open an html file.